# Выбрать из строки все аббревиатуры

Tags: java, строки

Найти аббревиатуры 2-6 символов, не считая числа:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "fv345vABCrfЯRЯ";
    String regEx = "(\\p{Lu}{2,6})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // как сделать вывод аббревиатур в виде списка?
    }
}
```

Пример: `String s = "fv345ABCrfЯRЯ";`

Вывод: `ABC ЯRЯ`

Comment: Добрый день, на этом сайте принято помогать с задачами, а не решать за кого-то либо. Поэтому, пожалуйста, добавьте вашу попытку решить задачу (в виде кода в вопросе), иначе вопрос может быть закрыт. Ознакомьтесь с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Цифры ведь не нужно учитывать? `Аббревиатурой будем считать слово от 2 до 6 символов, состоящее только из больших букв без чисел`

Comment: Я бы решил эту задачу через регулярное выражение, например: `[А-ЯA-Z]{2,6}`

Comment: то есть "СОБАКА" и "КОРОВА" - аббревиатуры?)

Comment: Цифры не учитываются, а "СОБАКА" и "КОРОВА" будут считаться за аббревиатуру, т.к. они написаны большими буквами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для распознавания *любых* заглавных букв (включая `Ё`) следует использовать класс `\p{Lu}` (сокращённое название для [`\p{Uppercase_Letter}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)).

Тогда можно распечатать список слов, похожих на аббревиатуры, следующим образом:

```
String s = "fv345ABCrfЯRЁЯ.КРАЇНА_Қазақстан/ЎРОК|PÂTÉfon";

Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}{2,6}")
    .matcher(s)
    .results() // Stream<MatchResult> 
    .map(MatchResult::group) // Stream<String> аббревиатуры
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
ABC
ЯRЁЯ
КРАЇНА
ЎРОК
PÂTÉ
```

Для получения списка/массива аббревиатур, вместо `forEach(System.out::println)` использовать метод `Stream::collect`  с соответствующим коллектором `Collectors.toList()`, `Stream::toList` (Java 16+), или `Stream::toArray`:

```java
List<String> abbrs = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}{2,6}")
    .matcher(s)
    .results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Без Stream API:

```java
List<String> abbrs = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}{2,6}").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    abbrs.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Использовать Stream API нельзя?  Что означает комментарий: _// как сделать вывод аббревиатур в виде списка?_  внутри цикла?

Comment: Можно, но есть вариант без преобразования в поток?

Comment: Создаёте экземпляр мутабельного списка _до цикла_: `List<String> abbrevs = new ArrayList<>();`, в цикле добавляете в него группу: `while (matcher.find()) { abbrevs.add(matcher.group());}`

Comment: спасибо, все работает